# ReactJs: Immutable Data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutability

I was doing the official ReactJs tutorial and I started to get confused about the meaning and application of immutability.

An example of the way I thought it was. Imagine i have an object in a constructor `this.state = { dog: some data}` and then I call a handleClick function which sets `this.setState = {dog: another data}`. Since I was using `setState` to update the value, the old reference would still be immutable, I could get to know what changed.

But in the tutorial, when they copy the "squares" state with `.slice()` to not change the original array and then apply the `setState` with a new value, I got confused.

Why they need to copy the array, couldnt they just make a reference of it in `setState` and change things there? The original reference would still be traceable...

EDIT:

@FelixKling Here:

```
class Board extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
       squares: Array(9).fill(null),
    };
  }

  handleClick(i) {
    const squares = this.state.squares.slice();
    squares[i] = 'X';
    this.setState({squares: squares});
  }
}
```

Couldn't they just put that inside the `setState`, instead of copying the initial array?

Comment: *"couldnt they just make a reference of it in setState and change things there"* What do you mean by that? Can you provide a concrete example of what they did and what you think they should do?

Comment: Please [edit] your question, include the code and format it properly. It's not that readable in comments.

Comment: @FelixKling edited the top post.

Comment: *"Couldn't they just put that inside the setState"* What exactly? Slicing the array?

Comment: When i have an object in "state", and update it in "setState is this a mutation?

Comment: The new state is built be (shallow) merging the argument passed to `setState` and the current state. Because objects are mutable, if they didn't slice the array but did `this.state.squares[i] = ...` instead, they would be modifying the array that is referenced by the current state.

Comment: But, couldnt they make `this.setState.squares[i] = this.state.squares[i].concat(...)`? Using this the reference state would be overwritten?

Comment: `setState` is a **function**. It doesn't make sense to add a property to it.

Answer (score 2):

This is a really great article that helps to explain why immutability is important: http://reactkungfu.com/2015/08/pros-and-cons-of-using-immutability-with-react-js/

> In fact, React.js does not need to have knowledge about *what exactly changed*. All it needs to know is whether the state *changed at all or not*.
>
> While immutability does not provide easier answers to a *what exactly changed* problem, it provides a great answer to the *is it changed at all or not* question.

React, as the name suggests 'reacts' to changes in sate and will re-render components as the state changes. So for React, knowing if the state changes is important, unfortunately, mutating an object can make it difficult to compare.

Consider this example:

```
var a = 6; // numbers are primatives in javascript and compare by value
var b = 6; 
var c = a; // 6

// in this case 
a === b // true
b === c // true, 6
```

But you can't do the same for objects as they are compared by reference, that is are they pointing to the same point in memory.

```
var objA = { name: 'Sally' };
var objB = { name: 'Sally' };
var objC = objA;

// these are not the same object
objA.name === objB.name // true, 'Sally'
objA === objB // false, they reference different objects even though the keys and values are the same
objA === objC // true, they reference the same point in memory
```

The issue that arrises in React is more easily illustrated when you try and modify a value.

Let's take our number example again and make some changes:

```
c = 14;
a === b // true, still 6, the value of 'a' is still 6
a === c // false, 6 ≠ 14
```

That makes, sense we've changed the value of c, it should now be different. Let's modify our objects now.

```
objA.age = 30; // give objA an age property    
objB.age = 35; // give objB an age property
objC.age = 40; // give objC an age property, actually changes objA

// now try equality
objA === objB // false, we already know this
objA.age === objB.age // false, as expected
objA.age === objC.age // true, possibly unexpected as it looks like we are comparing 30 to 40, but in fact our change to objC modified objA
objA === objC // true both have age set to 40
```

So if instead we give React a new state each time, instead of mutating it, then it's much easier to know if it should re-render.

You might be wondering then, why react doesn't just store a copy of the state and compare it to the mutated state. Maybe you're not wondering this, but it seems like this is something that React/Redux could handle and then we could just be free to mutate the state, making it easier for us.

Well it turns out that comparing two objects is quite an intensive task, first you have to make sure that they both have the same keys, and that those keys hold the same values - doesn't seem that hard - but then you realise that objects can contain many other nested objects and this comparison become recursive, checking each nested object.

It would be much easier to just pass in a new state, so that React can tell right away that it has changed.

On top of this, generating a new state also allows you to 'time travel' by keeping track of and storing previous states if you choose to.

Answer (score 0):

A bit further down in the tutorial they detail the importance of immutability:
https://facebook.github.io/react/tutorial/tutorial.html#why-immutability-is-important

You can also read a lot about Immutability here: https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/

Immutable JS is a library Facebook created for object Immutability

TLDR Links: It's basically easier to track changes and easier to determine when to re-render.

Edit regarding comment:

So you're correct that `this.setState` does update the object rather than mutating it.

In this example, we create a copy instead of mutating.

```
handleClick(i) {
  const squares = this.state.squares.slice();
  squares[i] = this.state.xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O';
  this.setState({
    squares: squares,
  });
}
```

In this example, we mutate instead of creating a copy

```
handleClick(i) {
  this.state.squares[i] = this.state.xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O';
  this.setState({
    squares: squares,
  });
}
```

For the first example where we did not mutate, when React runs through its lifecycle events after this.setState is called and gets to `shouldComponentUpdate`, here's what would happen

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    // this will return true and trigger an update
    return this.state.squares !== nextState;
}
```

For the second example, where we did mutate, here's what would happen:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    // this will return false and will not trigger an update
    return this.state.squares !== nextState;
}
```

and now, even though we've changed our state, since our current, mutated state is the same as our next state (set in this.setState) our react component won't update.

Comment: I understand the meaning, my doubt is in the application part. I tought that if i put some object in a constructor state and then update that object in a function with "setState" that the object would update but not mutate. Im confused on that part.

Comment: I added a bit more explanation about the importance of not mutating. Let me know if that clears it up.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So if we did this:

     `handleClick(i) {
      this.setState({
        squares: this.state.squares[i] = this.state.xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O' ,
      });
    }`

We would be overwriting the original state, and React would interpret that as a "no change was made" in setState?

Comment: Well whenever this.setState is called, it runs through `shouldComponentUpdate`, `componentWillUpdate`, `render`, and `componentDidUpdate`. To increase the speed of your application, if state is updated but doesn't change how anything is rendered then you would want to return false from `shouldComponentUpdate`, and it won't check the other methods and will stop the loop speeding up your application

Comment: However, if you mutated the state it messes up your ability to compare the nextState to the current state in `shouldComponentUpdate`. It's better to get into that workflow so when it does matter you aren't in the bad habit of it, especially as you go on to create larger components. 

Basically, React will automatically re-render on `this.setState` and you can prevent that re-render if you choose, but you can't do that with a mutated state being compared to itself.